# Parsing JSON data based on partial element response

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON response with around 10,000 responses in it all in this particular format

```
{"SessionName": "rdp-tcp", "userid": "TEST:3:09-48-16-04-48-00", "ComputerName": "SERVER1", "LogonTime": "2016-08-09T04:48:00"}
```

I would like to be able to pull out the responses that fit a certain criteria based on a match of a partial response

For example what i am trying to get is all the Logons that occured during 4am-5am

This could be achieved by being able to query on the following:

```
"LogonTime": "2016-08-09T04:48:00"
```

How can I with (for example with Javascript) match against a partial or startswith style query in JSON to pull out all responses that fit a particular chunk of text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should do it on server side. on front you can use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter entries by criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your array based on the `LogonTime`, getting the hour with [Date.prototype.getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours):

```js
var json = [{
        "SessionName": "rdp-tcp",
        "userid": "TEST:3:09-48-16-04-48-00",
        "ComputerName": "SERVER1",
        "LogonTime": "2016-08-09T02:48:00"
    }, {
        "SessionName": "rdp-tcp",
        "userid": "TEST:3:09-48-16-04-48-00",
        "ComputerName": "SERVER1",
        "LogonTime": "2016-08-09T03:48:00"
    }, {
        "SessionName": "rdp-tcp",
        "userid": "TEST:3:09-48-16-04-48-00",
        "ComputerName": "SERVER1",
        "LogonTime": "2016-08-09T04:48:00"
    }],
    arrResult = json.filter(function(elem) {
        var date = new Date(elem.LogonTime),
            hour = date.getUTCHours();
        return hour >= 4 && hour <= 5;
    });

console.log(arrResult);
```

Note that as @Maxx pointed on his comment you should implement this logic on server side and for performance do some pagination because `10,000` is a very large number.

Comment: Hi Yosvel,
Thank you. I ran your code to see how it works and it produces a empty array in the console?

Comment: Is your JSON an `array` of `objects`.. Is it ok? Can you show how is it?

Comment: Hi Yosvel, I copied your code from above into an ide and it just returns a empty array (it also does when i click run code snippet here). I have not attempted to apply my code to this yet, i wanted to see the above code running with a result :)

Comment: To confirm yes the data i am going to be parsing is an array

Comment: Hiya, your code absolutely helped me thank you so much. However for it to work it seems to need to use getUTCHours() - The time appears to be recorded in UTC

Comment: You right, has improved with the use of `getUTCHours()`. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple in javascript

1. First convert object into an array.
2. Use each function and compare date

```js
var logons = [];

yourObject.each(function (child){
  if(Date.parse(child['LogonTime']) > Date.parse('01/01/2011 04:00:00') && Date.parse(child['LogonTime']) > Date.parse('01/01/2011 5:00:00')){
    logons.push($(this));
}
});
```

**Note:** this code is not tested may be you will get syntax error